# ActionScript 3 - cannot access MovieClip on stage via root

Tags: actionscript-3, root, movieclip, visible

I have a movieclip called PointerMC. Inside PointerMC is a tween which has actionscript. PointerMC starts off as

```
pointerMC.visible=false;
```

. I have a MovieClip called playMC as well on the stage. Here is the AS:

playMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClick);

```
function playClick(evt:Event):void {
    pointerMC.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

and here is the AS inside pointerMC:

```
stop();
MovieClip(root).pointerMC.visible=true;
```

Now, when I click playMC, I want to make pointerMC visible and then play the tween inside PointerMC, I know I can do

```
function playClick(evt:Event):void {
    pointerMC.visible=true;
    pointerMC.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

but how do I make pointerMC visible while I am inside the MovieClip? How come

```
    MovieClip(root).pointerMC.visible=true;
```

is not making PointerMC visible?

Answer (score 1):

If you're already inside of `pointerMC`, then you shouldn't have to use `root` to access it, you can just use the `this` keyword: `this.visible = true;`

Comment: why doesn't "MovieClip(root).pointerMC.visible=true;" work though?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but I did run a test in which I had a MovieClip with 2 frames, first frame had a `stop` command, second frame had `MovieClip(root).pointerMC.visible = true;` and it actually worked. Are you certain that `pointerMC` is actually found in the root?  Still, it doesn't seem like good practice to go out to the root level when you don't actually need to.